# jQuery function triggers twice

Tags: jquery

I have this code http://jsfiddle.net/8dFVU/ and not sure why it triggers twice when you click on the "show price" I guess it is because the checkbox and label but, why? Thanks.

here is the code

```
(function($){ 
        $(".selector").on('click', function() { 
            console.log(  $(this) );  
            $("#result").val( $("#result").val() +"triggered" );
        });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clicking on a `<label>` will also generate a click event for its corresponding control.

Your `click` handler on the parent element sees both of these click events – the real one from the label and the generated one from the checkbox.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Do you know how to prevent that?

Comment: @user2360754: How to prevent which part of that?

Comment: preventing the double return. All i want to run the the function only one time, however return false is not a solution, it also stops my function.

Answer (score 1):

Change function to:

```
(function($){ 
    $(".selector").on('click', function() { 
        console.log(  $(this) );  
        $("#result").val( $("#result").val() +"triggered" );
        return false;
    });
})(jQuery);
```

As both div and checkbox will trigger click event.

Comment: `this` will always be the same.  You mean `e.target`

Comment: @Slaks, yes you are right, as I tested clicking on checkbox, one single trigger is recorded. On label 2.